# How to use Enzyme's mount using JEST

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

Everytime I import mount from Enzyme and try and use it to mount one of my Components for testing, i get the following error: "It looks like you called `mount()` without a global document being loaded". What I want to know is, do I have to set up a "jest-setup.js" file or something similar and add jsdom as a global? Please advice. Have been searching the web for answers with no luck

Comment: I think this guide should help you https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/jsdom.md

Answer (score 0):

Jest comes bundled with JSDOM, so you just need to make sure you run with `testEnvironment: jsdom` (which is the default).